# Session Id's, UUID's and GUID's and just ID's in general

Tags: php, session-state, uniqueidentifier, sessionid

I have an idea. It might be bad, for reasons not known by me, but I would really appreciate your feedback on this!

We've been using Session ID's in a PHP project. And for the first time in 4 years, a duplicate sessionid was generated. Luckily enough I randomly decided to go looking through the Customers Table because I was bored and noticed there was a duplicate entry in the sessionid column and changed it, and references to it, before any real problems occured.

Which led (or lead?) me to ask myself this question:

Basically, any type of ID, be it a session id, uuid or guid can eventually be duplicated because the length of them is not infinite. So then I got thinking, because we never want this to happen again.

I thought, What if we use a combination of date *and* time, as an identifier? This wouldn't be "random", but it would solve the duplication issue. For example:

```
14th of May 2011 04:36:05PM
```

If used as an identifier, could be changed to:

```
14052011163605
```

The reason this form of ID will never become duplicated is because no date, combined with time in the future will ever be the same as one in the past, or present.

And since, in our case, these ID's are not meant to be seen by anybody, there's no reason for it to be random, is there?

I'd love to hear your thoughts on this, and, how you approach situations like this. What's your best method of generating [practically] unique ID'S?

Comment: You need to focus on the technology a bit when you are dealing with session ids. Added PHP tag for you.

Comment: Are you 1000% sure a duplicate session ID was created? I think there are some additional checks to prevent that from happening, not just a randomizer. Are you sure it wasn't the same user logging in and out from two accounts or something?

Comment: Definitely duplicated. I'm in the middle of going over all of the code that deals with sessionid's in the project, just incase it's a problem on our end, but if that's the case it would've happened more than once, I'd assume. An account was created 6 months ago, and a sessionid was associated with it. And lastnight, a new account was created, and both sessionid's were exactly the same. If I had not clicked on the Column header in Navicat for MySQL, I never would've spotted it.

Comment: Why are your sessions sticking around for 6 months?

Comment: @ceejayoz - We don't like to remove information about, or even slightly related to a user, their actions on the website or our software. In fact, every little bit of information, no matter how little it is, helps us.

Comment: If you're using them like that, they're not really sessions. Why not just use their user ID, or a hash of it?

Comment: I'm not too sure as to *why* they decided to use them like this. But I do know *how* they're used. And it kinda makes sense to me. We use them initially as Sessions. But they decided that once they've used them as sessions, they wanted to use them as a sort of Reference ID for various 'Actions' that are performed by that user. For example, each set of 'Actions' for UserId within a single Session is grouped into its own Session Id.

Comment: So we could do something like: *SELECT Action FROM Actions WHERE UserId = @0* Etc. Where Action is a Column full of Session Id's.

Answer (score 4):

> The reason this form of ID will never become duplicated is because no date, combined with time in the future will ever be the same as one in the past, or present.

If you only had one user, this would be true.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand *why* this would be un-true, **unless** more than one ID was generated within the same millisecond.?

Comment: @Lucifer - The chances of creating more than one ID in the same millisecond are much higher than the changes of generating the same GUID.

Answer (score 3):

UUID / GUIDs are very large (larger than the count of particles in visible universe)

your date/time solution will fail on high loads.  what happens when i need 100+ new ids per second ?

Comment: Gah I hate to call you on this but there are 2^128 unique guids which is about 3 x 10^38 .....The mass of the visible universe is about 3 x 10^54 kg.

Comment: do we really need to quibble over a measly precision difference of 3x10^54 or so ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make your session ID column a unique column, and then generate a new session ID if you get a constraint violation error? That way the database will find this problem for you in basically the same way that you did (and as a bonus, it can fix it too).

Comment: That sounds pretty logical, I guess the creative side of me blocked my logical thought process and decided it wanted to create a new form of Identification. This sounds like a pretty cool solution, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

UUIDs are already generated based on nanosecond intervals of time (see this [wikipeida article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)). If you are using PHP, I'd suggest this page to take a look at how to generate the different versions, depending on your use:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

The reason you can't guarantee uniqueness is that you *have* to eventually pick a size limit for the actual string/variable containing your UUID, so there is always the potential for a duplicate. Given the number of possibilities for a UUID, though, this should be practically impossible.

I agree with the other posters... this probably shouldn't ever happen. How are you actually generating unique IDs? Are you sure your code is properly creating them?

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm still going over all of the code again in our project to make sure it's not a mistake one of us made, but over a period of time, I've seen, edited and added to all of the code in the project, and I'd assume if not noticed a problem, it would've atleast happened more than once.?